# As of the latest major Windows 10 update in the last week I can't access saved site passwords for browsers, is there a fix?

Tags: windows-10, browser, passwords, password-management

This is affecting both Opera and Chrome. I've seen a few articles about Windows Credentials Manager and suggestions about switching from a Windows to a local account didn't work for me.

Is there a way to regain access to stored, encrypted passwords Windows manages? Or will I be stuck having to just reset the credential store from scratch and begin anew (though I'll probably use a separate password manager application going forward)?

Comment: Chrome passwords are working here (as also with Chromium Edge) . Have you update both Edge and Chrome (now V86)

Comment: Can you throw more light on the problem, are there any error messages, or in the Event Viewer? Are the browsers all updated? Normally each browser has a different mechanism for storing website passwords, so Windows is not to blame. BTW, I recommend LastPass.

Comment: @John Yes I've verified both Edge and Chrome are the latest versions.

Comment: @harrymc No error messages to speak of and nothing pops out of the event logs but if there's anything specific you suggest looking for I can. This began just after a major Windows update, upon rebooting I found that sites I'd saved passwords for were prompting me without any dropdown allowing me to choose as is typically the case. Some articles I'd read suggested that the WCM component could be part of the problem as I haven't been using a separate password manager, just Windows and/or the browsers' password storage.